# Aptana Studio 3.3.0 crashes on start - Arch Linux

Tags: linux, aptana3

here's my system specs;

```
Arch Linux x86_64, 
Kernel: 3.6.10-1-ARCH, 
Gnome 3.6.2, 
xf86-video-nouveau 1.0.4-1, 
jdk7-openjdk 7.u9_2.3.3-1,  
jre7-openjdk 7.u9_2.3.3-1, 
jre7-openjdk-headless 7.u9_2.3.3-1,
lib32-libjpeg-turbo 1.2.1-1, libjpeg-turbo 1.2.1-1, libjpeg6-turbo 1.2.1-1
libpng12 1.2.50-2,
net-tools 1.60.20120804git-2,
unzip 6.0-6.
```

Ok, so there's the list of requirements that are installed, version numbers as well.  Upon launch, the loading/splash screen won't even show, and then nothing... it just dies out.  I attempted to launch it "`aptana -v`" and no output in the shell.  I have looked for any error logs in `~/` , but nothing is there.

Other steps I've done is to delete any configuration folders/files for eclipse and aptana-secure in `~/`.  Also did a clean uninstall of just Aptana (not the dependencies), reinstall.  Same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I stand corrected.. after some digging, hopefully this will help others.  It appears that the 32 bit and the 64 bit somehow got mixed up. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7619 and https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7620 verify this.

Comment: I'm confused. Did you figure out the problem? If so, write it up as an answer and accept that so it's clearer -- no need to put solved in the title.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a mix up in the downloads. 32-bit and 64-bit got switched. If you are on 32-bit download 64-bit and vice versa. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

See issues below:

- [Aptana 64 bit version crashes on startup on 64bit Linux OS with 64bit Oracle 7 java](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7619)
- [Linux Installer Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_3.3.0.zip contains x64 bit version of the project](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7620)